# Azure TTS generating garbled result when requesting Opus encoding

Tags: c++, linux, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, opus

The following sample code (C++, Linux, x64) uses the MS Speech SDK to request a text-to-speech of a single sentence in Opus format with no container. It then uses the Opus lib to decode to raw PCM. Everything seems to run with no errors but the result sounds garbled, as if some of the audio is missing, and the result `Done, got 14880 bytes, decoded to 24000 bytes` looks like this might be a decoding issue rather than an Azure issue as I'd expect a much higher compression ratio.

Note that this generates a raw PCM file, play back with: `aplay out.raw -f S16_LE -r 24000 -c 1`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <speechapi_cxx.h>
#include <opus.h>

using namespace Microsoft::CognitiveServices::Speech;

static const std::string subscription_key = "abcd1234"; // insert valid key here
static const std::string service_region = "westus";
static const std::string text = "Hi, this is Azure";
static const int sample_rate = 24000;
#define MAX_FRAME_SIZE 6*960 // from Opus trivial_example.c

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // create Opus decoder
    int err;
    OpusDecoder* opus_decoder = opus_decoder_create(sample_rate, 1, &err);
    assert(err == OPUS_OK);

    // create Azure client
    auto azure_speech_config = SpeechConfig::FromSubscription(subscription_key, service_region);
    azure_speech_config->SetSpeechSynthesisVoiceName("en-US-JennyNeural");
    azure_speech_config->SetSpeechSynthesisOutputFormat(SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat::Audio24Khz16Bit48KbpsMonoOpus);
    auto azure_synth = SpeechSynthesizer::FromConfig(azure_speech_config, NULL);

    FILE* fp = fopen("out.raw", "w");
    int in_bytes=0, decoded_bytes=0;

    // callback to capture incoming packets
    azure_synth->Synthesizing += [&in_bytes, &decoded_bytes, fp, opus_decoder](const SpeechSynthesisEventArgs& e) {
        printf("Synthesizing event received with audio chunk of %zu bytes\n", e.Result->GetAudioData()->size());
        auto audio_data = e.Result->GetAudioData();
        in_bytes += audio_data->size();

        // confirm that this is exactly one valid Opus packet
        assert(opus_packet_get_nb_frames((const unsigned char*)audio_data->data(), audio_data->size()) == 1);

        // decode the packet
        std::vector<uint8_t> decoded_data(MAX_FRAME_SIZE);
        int decoded_frame_size = opus_decode(opus_decoder, (const unsigned char*)audio_data->data(), audio_data->size(),
                (opus_int16*)decoded_data.data(), decoded_data.size()/sizeof(opus_int16), 0);
        assert(decoded_frame_size > 0); // confirm no decode error

        decoded_frame_size *= sizeof(opus_int16); // result size is in samples, convert to bytes
        printf("Decoded to %d bytes\n", decoded_frame_size);
        assert(decoded_frame_size <= (int)decoded_data.size());
        fwrite(decoded_data.data(), 1, decoded_frame_size, fp);
        decoded_bytes += decoded_frame_size;
    };

    // perform TTS
    auto result = azure_synth->SpeakText(text);
    printf("Done, got %d bytes, decoded to %d bytes\n", in_bytes, decoded_bytes);

    // cleanup
    fclose(fp);
    opus_decoder_destroy(opus_decoder);
}
```

Comment: If I do the math quickly, 24 Khz * 2 bytes per sample is 48 KB/s. Your buffer is 6*960 bytes or 2880 samples or 120ms' worth. What if the callback sends you more than 120ms? Check with `opus_decoder_get_nb_samples` how many samples you actually received. I bet it is a lot more than 2880 (120 ms).

Comment: @Botje, each individual packet is 600 encoded bytes (except the first and last, 720 and 360 respecitvely) and decodes to 960 bytes. If the buffer is any smaller than 960 bytes the decode will fail. Enlarging it has no effect. opus_packet_get_nb_samples reports 480 samples, and I ensure there is exactly one packet with opus_packet_get_nb_frames. I've also tried opus_packet_parse and it agrees with these figures.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas. The abysmal compression ratio seems to suggest there's data missing somewhere, but I have no idea where. Can you try the same API a different way to know what size it would otherwise generate?

Comment: @Botje There is a simpler API that doesn't utilize a callback: After the call to `SpeakText` I can do `auto azure_synth_stream = AudioDataStream::FromResult(result);` then `ReadData` from that stream. I get the same result data except it's no longer conveniently divided into Opus packets.

Comment: The same amount of bytes / samples as well? If not, that would support the theory you are losing data somewhere. And more importantly, does the direct method work properly?

Comment: @Botje If I call `ReadData` then I get the same result data: a single buffer of 14880 bytes which are the same data as if I had taken the individual packets received in the `Synthesizing` lambda and saved them all to a single file. I've done some experimenting with the decoding and parsing functions in <opus.h> and found nothing that can consistently parse this data. If I call `opus_decode` on it I get `OPUS_INVALID_PACKET` but if I set the len to 720 (size of the first packet) then I get a success. But there's no way I could have known that 720 value without prior knowledge.

Comment: I wonder if Azure is giving you [self-delimiting Opus packets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6716#appendix-B), which is not supported in the public `opus_decode` API. (Although the private API [implements it](https://github.com/xiph/opus/blob/master/src/opus_decoder.c))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received no useful response to this question (I've also asked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1005079/azure-tts-generating-garbled-result-when-requestin.html) and [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1653) and even tried Azure's paid support) so I gave up and switched from `Audio24Khz16Bit48KbpsMonoOpus` to `Ogg48Khz16BitMonoOpus` which means the Opus encoding is wrapped in an Ogg container, requiring the rather cumbersome libopusfile API to decode. It was kind of a pain to implement but it does the job.